# What are the best resources for learning about theory choice?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

There’s a small [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_choice) describing how philosophers have throughout history come up with criteria to decide between theories that attempt to explain certain observations. What I am interested in are dedicated and best resources on this topic.

Comment: See [The Structure of Scientific Theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structure-scientific-theories/) and [Scientific Revolutions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-revolutions/) and [The Incommensurability of Scientific Theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/incommensurability/) and [Historicist Theories of Scientific Rationality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationality-historicist/).